# How can I get correct/expected opacity to apply to elements that are displayed using $().fadeIn() in IE8?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I have a weird CSS/jQuery gotcha that I can't figure out.

I have three forms on my page, but only one can be displayed at a time, so I hide all them by default using CSS

```
form fieldset {
    display: none;
}
```

I then display them dynamically using jQuery method fadeIn().

However, when I call the fadeIn() method on the each fieldset, the CSS rules for the label fonts are not being applied in IE8. IE Developer Tools *says* that font-family is `Verdana, Arial, sans-serif`, but the labels are all displayed with Arial.

CSS:

```
label {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="State">
    State *:
</label>
```

Comment: Actually, I think I found the cause of the problem. fadeIn() applies an alpha filter to the element. This causes the font to appear different than expected. Is there away to eliminate the filter when using fadeIn(). For the time being, I'm just going to use slideUp() and slideDown() - I like them better anyways!

Comment: It turns out slide effects are not much better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here's the best solution I could come up with:

```
$(this).fadeTo(350, 1, function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("style").css("display", "block");
        myHide($addressFormFieldSet);
        myHide($uploadFormFieldSet);
    });
}
```